# Boolean setter wrong output

Tags: java, methods, boolean, output, setter

When I'm calling the `BookClass` in the main method, the only output from status is `true` or `false`. 
Why wont it print out the `if-else` statement in my Setter?

```
public class Book {

private String title;
private int year;
private String author;
private boolean status;

public Book(String title, int year, String author, boolean status){
    this.title = title;
    this.year = year;
    this.author = author;
    this.status = status;
    }

public void setStatus(boolean status){
    this.status = status;   
    if(status){
        System.out.println("Unavailable");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Available");
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you call `setStatus`?

Comment: Show your `main` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use function `setStaus` in your constructor as setters and getters do not work implicitly:

```
public Book(String title, int year, String author, boolean status){
    this.title = title;
    this.year = year;
    this.author = author;
    setStatus(status);
}
```